# Is there webmail with labels synchronized with IMAP?

Tags: email, imap

Is there any webmail apps with labels, that are synchronized (as keywords) with IMAP protocol?

There is GMail, but GMail doesn't have labels in truth, but folders that looks like labels.

In Czech, there is e-mail provider Seznam.cz which also has labels, but neither these labels are not synchronized over IMAP.